# Checkbox always checked custom styling

Tags: jquery

I have a newsletter subscription CF7 form on my site that I have integrated with Mailchimp for Wordpress. Initially, it was checked only when you click on the checkbox. Since I wanted it to have custom styling checkbox tick icon, I added jQuery to add a class to it when ticked. The jQuery looked something like this:

```js
jQuery(".mc4wp-checkbox label").mousedown(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass("checked")) {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("checked")
  } else {
    jQuery(this).addClass("checked")
  }
});
```

```css
.checked { color: #C00; }
.mc4wp-checkbox label input {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 6px !important;
right: 0;
width: auto;
opacity: 0;
}
.mc4wp-checkbox label:before {
content: '' !important;
border: 2px solid #bbb !Important;
border-radius: 5px !Important;
cursor: pointer !Important;
display: inline-block !important;
float: right !Important;
height: 49px !important;
position: relative !Important;
top: 0 !important;
margin-left: 20px !important;
margin-top: -15px !Important;
width: 48px !important;
}
.mc4wp-checkbox input:checked+label:before,
.mc4wp-checkbox label.checked:before {
background: #000;
background-position: center center !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-size: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> 
  <span class="newsletter">
    <input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_subscribe_contact-form-7" value="0" />
    <span class="mc4wp-checkbox mc4wp-checkbox-contact-form-7">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="_mc4wp_subscribe_contact-form-7" value="1" checked="checked" />
        <span>Sign up for our newsletter</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

But now I've changed the checkbox to always be checked, and the user can uncheck it if they don't want to subscribe. But now the jquery above won't work the same way anymore because it was meant to add the class only when someone clicks on the checkbox. How can I have it so that the class is always there, and when the checkbox is clicked, then it removes the class?

Bear in mind that because I'm using a plugin, there's no html that I can edit, I was only provided with a shortcode and that's why I'm using jquery.

Comment: You can use `classToggle()` instead of `if`/`else`

Comment: Could you please add the relevant HTML. I would suggest you use the `change` event on the checkbox itself though, instead of the `mousedown` event on the `label`

Comment: @Eddie I think you mean `toggleClass()`

Comment: You are right. `toggleClass()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just edited the question to add the HTML

Comment: Thank you. I placed the HTML and JS you provided in a snippet where it appears to work correctly. Please check the DOM in your local version, and check if the class is being added and if the CSS associated to it is being over-ridden

Comment: And how would that toggleClass() look like? I'm still a bit shaky in jquery

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass Although note that that is just making your logic more succinct, it won't affect any logical issues you have

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The thing is I want a custom styled checkbox so I disabled the input checkbox and I added styling to the :before pseudo class. The custom checkbox tick is the class I want to add. I've edited the snippet so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So currently, the background only becomes black when the checkbox is checked, and that's because of the jQuery. I want it to have a black background on default, since the checkbox is also checked by default, and only when I click on it should it be empty. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ah I see, I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So currently, the background only becomes black when the checkbox is checked, and that's because of the jQuery. I want it to have a black background on default, since the checkbox is also checked by default, and only when I click on it should it be empty.

In this case you simply need to trigger a `mousedown` event when the page loads, in order for the class state to be updated on the element. You can use `trigger()` to do this. Also note that you can use `toggleClass()` to make your logic more succinct:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".mc4wp-checkbox label").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("checked");
  }).trigger('mousedown');
});
```

```css
.mc4wp-checkbox label input {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 6px !important;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}

.mc4wp-checkbox label:before {
  content: '' !important;
  border: 2px solid #bbb !Important;
  border-radius: 5px !Important;
  cursor: pointer !Important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: right !Important;
  height: 49px !important;
  position: relative !Important;
  top: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 20px !important;
  margin-top: -15px !Important;
  width: 48px !important;
}

.mc4wp-checkbox input:checked+label:before,
.mc4wp-checkbox label.checked:before {
  background: #000;
  background-position: center center !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <span class="newsletter">
    <input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_subscribe_contact-form-7" value="0" />
    <span class="mc4wp-checkbox mc4wp-checkbox-contact-form-7">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="_mc4wp_subscribe_contact-form-7" value="1" checked="checked" />
        <span>Sign up for our newsletter</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

That being said you should really not be using the `mousedown` event on the parent `label` when dealing with checkboxes. You should instead listen for the `change` event on the checkbox itself, like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".mc4wp-checkbox :checkbox").on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('label').toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.mc4wp-checkbox label input {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 6px !important;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}

.mc4wp-checkbox label:before {
  content: '' !important;
  border: 2px solid #bbb !Important;
  border-radius: 5px !Important;
  cursor: pointer !Important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: right !Important;
  height: 49px !important;
  position: relative !Important;
  top: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 20px !important;
  margin-top: -15px !Important;
  width: 48px !important;
}

.mc4wp-checkbox input:checked+label:before,
.mc4wp-checkbox label.checked:before {
  background: #000;
  background-position: center center !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <span class="newsletter">
    <input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_subscribe_contact-form-7" value="0" />
    <span class="mc4wp-checkbox mc4wp-checkbox-contact-form-7">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="_mc4wp_subscribe_contact-form-7" value="1" checked="checked" />
        <span>Sign up for our newsletter</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: @Jacqui there's an upvote button as well as an "accept" button :)